# Switch between Tablet or Mobile content

Tags: kendo-ui

I would like to separate Tablet and Mobile views, I choose it in the definition of the application. But it fails, nothing happens once I run the application. Here is a piece of code:

```html
<div id="phoneApp">
   <div data-role="view" id="home">
       <h1>Phone Home</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="view" id="about">
       <h1>Phone About</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="layout" data-id="phoneDefault">
       <div data-role="header">
          <div data-role="navbar">
                Phone App
          </div>                       
       </div>
       <!--Content--> 
       <div data-role="footer">
           <div data-role="tabstrip">
             <a href="#home" data-icon="home">Home</a>
             <a href="#about" data-icon="info">About</a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application($("#phoneApp"), {transition: "slide", layout: "phoneDefault" });
</script>
```

I am trying to reproduce this example: http://jsfiddle.net/toddanglin/YGUeJ/5/, on fiddler it works, on my PC it doesnt.

Am I forgetting something?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding the CSS definition:

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

as you have in the Fiddle?